# SQL JOIN for Duplicate Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following two tables:

A.

```
A_ID Amount GL_ID
------------------
1    100    10
2    200    11
3    150    10
4    20     10
5    369    12
6    369    11
7    254    12
```

B.

```
B_ID Name GL_ID
-----------------
1    A    10
2    B    10
3    C    11
4    D    11
5    E    12
6    F    12
```

I want to join these tables. They have GL_ID column in common (ID of another table). Table A store transactions along with GL_ID while table B defines document type (A, B, C, D etc.) with reference to GL_ID.

A & B don't have any common column except GL_ID. I want the following result, relevant document type (A, B, C, D etc.) for each transaction in table A.

```
A.A_ID A.Amount B.Name
-----------------------
1      100      A
2      200      B
3      150      B
4      20       B
5      369      A
6      369      D
7      254      D
```

But when I apply to join (LEFT, RIGHT, FULL JOIN) keyword, query shows repeated values. But I only want to have relevant Doc Type for each line in table A.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Edit your question and at least explain the logic.

Comment: at  ...  least  ...   the logic

Comment: What you show in the tables and the result you would like do not have same data like the BCA result, or two times ABC ... you need to give us more details about your needs, it's not enought clear to give you a good answer.

Comment: Do you know how to use the `JOIN` keyword?

Comment: I have edited the question and mentioned the logic. Sorry to all of you for ambiguous question. . . . . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this.

select distinct A.A_ID, A.Amount, B.Name
from A inner join B on A.GL_ID=B.GL_ID